# Remove PulseAudio device

Tags: linux, audio, pulseaudio

While following instructions, I loaded a module which creates an input device "Monitor of Null Output" and an output device "Null Output" using this command:

```
pactl load-module module-null-sink sink_name=rmd
```

This is not what I wanted. How do I remove these two devices?

`pactl list` shows:

```
Sink #2
        State: IDLE
        Name: rmd
        Description: Null Output
        Driver: module-null-sink.c
        Sample Specification: s16le 2ch 48000Hz
        Channel Map: front-left,front-right
        Owner Module: 24
        Mute: no
        Volume: front-left: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB,   front-right: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB
                balance 0.00
        Base Volume: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB
        Monitor Source: rmd.monitor
        Latency: 1569 usec, configured 40000 usec
        Flags: DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY 
        Properties:
                device.description = "Null Output"
                device.class = "abstract"
                device.icon_name = "audio-card"
        Formats:
                pcm
```

I tried

```
pactl unload-module rmd
pactl unload-module sink_name=rmd
pactl unload-module "Null Output"
```

all of which respond with:

```
Failed to unload module: Module Null Output not loaded
```

etc.

I can run `pactl unload-module module-null-sink` but this removes all devices loaded with that module. How do I remove the device or unload the module which created the device specified above?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

`pactl unload-module` gives a hint:

```
You have to specify a module index or name
```

as does the manpage:

```
   unload-module ID|NAME
          Unload  the module instance identified by the specified numeric
          index or unload all modules by the specified name.
```

The ID is shown in this line (`pactl list`):

```
        Owner Module: 24
```

Just run

```
pactl unload-module 24
```

to remove the respective devices.

Comment: In case this is not persistent, meaning that the module will be loaded again on the next boot, how to make it persistent?
I guess I could set up a script that runs `pactl unload-module <module-id>` at startup but is there a less hacky solution?

Comment: Have a look at the configuration files in `/etc/pulse` (in particular `/etc/pulse/defailt.pa`) and comment out the line where the module is loaded.

Comment: For `sudo pactl unload-module 34`   says : `no valid command specified.` Same for it's name `viper.2`  I have installed Viper4Linux, it's setup oddly lacks the option to cancel, so I installed Viper over HDMI option, and over itself as well. Can't remove it and Viper4Linux also doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: can you reload the module somehow?

Comment: It seems `pactl unload-module` is not yet implemented when using PipeWire. According to [this](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/PipeWire/Examples) try the following: "In order to unload module, you can use `pw-cli destroy ID`, where `ID` is output of pactl load-module command."

Comment: @MatthiasBraun works for me on pipewire `0.3.56`. Well, "works" with the exception that you have to specify a module ID, the name doesn't work. I kinda hoped this answer would tell how to make it work, but apparently nope :c