# How to make audio switch back to HDMI on headphone disconnect?

Tags: audio, pulseaudio

On my `default.pa` I have `load-module module-switch-on-connect`, which works to make audio stream to automatically switch to headphones when I connect them. I use my PC connected to my TV through HDMI, and HDMI audio should be the fallback sink, not my PC internal audio device. When I turn on my PC, it plays through HDMI, when I connect my bluetooth headphones it switches to it, then, when I disconnect it, pulseaudio switches to internal audio instead of HDMI audio, even if I've set HDMI as `set-default-sink` in my `default.pa` (it looks like `set-default-sink` is one hit command).

How to fix this?

### Edit

I learned [from this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/263263/remove-pulseaudio-device) that unloading the specific module for my internal devices removes it, which leaves HDMI as the sole fallback available. I'm not sure how to make it permanent, since I have to run `pactl unload-module 7`, where 7 was the *current* "owner module", I've put unload-module 7 on my `default.pa` and it works but, ideally, I don't wish to remove the device entirely, I just want to have a proper fallback.