# PulseAudio: How to send a virtual sink's output to my headphones

Tags: pulseaudio

I created a virtual sink according to [How can I create a virtual output in PulseAudio?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/174379/how-can-i-create-a-virtual-output-in-pulseaudio) using:

```
pacmd load-module module-null-sink sink_name=MySink
pacmd update-sink-proplist MySink device.description=MySink
```

Now I want to also hear anything sent to MySink on my headphones. Is that possible?

I'm doing this so I can listen to music while I am recording videos but not record that music. I do want to record an application's audio output though (speech output).

Comment: I just tried something similar, are you sure, that you want a `module-null-sink`. According to the [docs](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/Documentation/User/Modules/#module-null-sink) it silently drops everything sent into it.

Answer (score 0):

[module-combine-sink](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/Documentation/User/Modules/#module-combine-sink) - creates a virtual sink that duplicates data to several other sinks

module can be enabled in 'paprefs' GUI - 'Simultaneous Playback' tab

or this command:

```
pactl load-module module-combine-sink
```