# Pulseaudio record multiple xfbv screens with python

Tags: python, selenium, ffmpeg, alsa, pulseaudio

I’m trying to do something complicated and I need some help.

I’m able to record a session (video and audio) with python using xvfb and ffmpeg.

I just want to visit a page using selenium and record the video and audio. It’s working but when I try to run multiple instances, the audio is mixing between records.

How can achieve that? I’m using pulseaudio. I know that with alsa you can set like a interface per instance, but I don’t know how to do it.

Thanks for you support and comments.

Comment: Welcome to U&L! What OS are you using, in case the packaged versions make a difference?

Comment: Have you tried [creating additional sinks](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/174379/how-can-i-create-a-virtual-output-in-pulseaudio) and recording their individual monitors?

Comment: That’s what I want. How can I create multiple sinks and assign each sink to ffmpeg?